# Debug Angular's $http.jsonp(); on Safari iOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, safari, arduino, jsonp

I have this code on my Angular App controller:

```
$http.jsonp('http://192.168.1.210/json', config).success(function (data) {
    vm.lightSensor = data.a0-vm.lightThreshold;
    vm.detected = (data.d2==1) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
    vm.toggle = (data.d7==1) ? 'on' : 'off';
    vm.jsonerror = false;
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert(status);
    vm.jsonerror = true;
});
```

It throws a 404 status error when I do the alert, however, this happens on Safari iOS but not on iOS Chrome, where the request works fine.

I think, as the server is an Arduino, that it may be something to do with the request headers that Safari iOS is sending, that maybe the Arduino server doesn't like and returns a 404 error.

I tried to debug it with weinre, but it doesn't show any xhr requests (at least for me).

What other not-too-tedious ways are there to debug the request so I can see what headers are being sent considering that I don't have a Mac?

Comment: you need to append callback in query parameter, URL will become like this `http://192.168.1.210/json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK`

Comment: Thanks @PankajParkar but that's not it, it's on the ``config`` variable being passed to the ``jsonp()`` function. Besides, the request is being done like that as debugging in the Chrome Dev tools show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved it. I could look at the headers by modifying the Arduino server to output the headers in the arduino serial console.

Turns out the problem was the arduino server itself, it didn't return a 200 code so it failed in Safari iOS. Somehow it still worked on the rest of the browsers, but I have no clue why.